# Drupal scheduler doesn't seems to work

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, cron, drupal-modules

I installed a drupal scheduler module and enabled it for a content type, i also installed supercron module to run the cron.

But it doesn't unpublish content on defined time.

i also tried to run cron.php and supercron.php file to unpublish the content but it doesn't seem to work in my case. can anybody help me in this.

Comment: Do you have promoted to front page checked for those articles? As far as I know, the scheduler just changes the "published" flag on the article so if you haven't promoted it you might not see it on your front page.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any caching modules installed? The post maybe unpublished but the page is not updated because the page is still cached. Also, you will need to check the clock on the server is set correctly. Maybe the server is not in your timezone and you either need to edit the php.ini or .htaccess file.